# What causes this compiler error in a small modular C program?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have written the following simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num1, num2;
int sum(int, int);

int main(void);
{
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    sum(num1, num2);
    return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{ 
    int res;
    res = a + b;
    return res;
}
```

But it produces the following compiler error:

> prog.c:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

The semicolon after the declaration of the `main` function:

```
int main(void);
```

is being interpreted by the compiler as marking the end of that function. Because the semicolon is there, it doesn't know what to do with the block of code that follows the declaration of that function. That's what the compliation error is telling you:

> prog.c:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token

It doesn't know what to do with the `{` that comes after the semicolon token, which indicates the end of a statement.

Removing the semicolon is the simple solution; rewrite your main function like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    sum(num1,num2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

As for the problem brought up in the comments:

> see when i run the output it asks for entering two numbers and doesnot show any sum result ??

Ah, that's a completely different problem. The code is syntactically correct, so you don't get any more compiler errors, but it's got a **logic** error! You never told the computer to *print* the sum of those two numbers to the screen. You need to insert another `printf` statement, just like the first one that you have. But this time, you want to print the value returned by the `sum` function.

The final code might look something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    printf("%d\n", sum(num1, num2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Demian: That's the only reason I posted the answer, instead of simply upvoting yours. You had it right first, but you didn't explain the cause. Having the fix is certainly worth something, but the explanation is worth a whole lot more!

Comment: can i know what i have to do to get result as in sum of two numbers also

Comment: see when i run the output it asks for entering two numbers and doesnot show any sum result ??

Comment: @Cody I'd delete mine if you add the printf to yours :)

Answer (score 0):

`int main(void);` remove the `;` from that line.

Comment: no but I will be getting some other error and my program is not running

Comment: @Sudheendra compiles fine for me after removing that.  Another of the answerers is correct in saying you don't capture your sum in a variable or output it.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5684852/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `int main(void);` with `int main(void)` (no ";")

Answer (score 0):

There is a semicolon after the prototype of `main`:

```
int main(void);
```

So there is not a definition of `main` in your program:

```
int main(void) { /*  */ }
```

The compiler is expecting either a function name or a struct name before a '{'.